# Android Studio Cannot Resolve MapView Class

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, mapview

while adding the mapview to the layout, I am encountering the following error. How can I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the SDK, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Google Maps Play Services dependency in the `app/build.gradle` file:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'`

Remember also to configure you project to add a map into your app: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config

Comment: i did but didn't work. it's give same error again